# Laravel - How to automatically logout and redirect to login page after inactivity for 30 minutes

Tags: laravel, session, logout

I would like a page to `redirect` to the Login page automatically if there is no activity for 30 minutes in my Laravel project. I've set `SESSION_LIFETIME` to 30 mins in my `ENV` file. How can I achieve it in Laravel?

Comment: To be clear, would you like the user who is inactive whilst on the web page to be automatically logged out and redirected to the login page?

Comment: Yes, If the user is inactive for some time on the web page - automatically logged out and moved to Login page

Comment: Are you using jQuery within your frontend?

Comment: Yes, Using jQuery in frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this in your header file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      var idleMax = 30; // Logout after 30 minutes of IDLE
      var idleTime = 0;

      var idleInterval = setInterval("timerIncrement()", 60000);  // 1 minute interval    
      $( "body" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
          idleTime = 0; // reset to zero
    });

    // count minutes
    function timerIncrement() {
        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        if (idleTime > idleMax) { 
            window.location="LogOut.php";
        }
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: How to handle the same thing in Laravel? Maybe we can handle it via middleware or handler or auth controller. Any idea?

Comment: In laravel you can using config\session.php, use lifetime param

Comment: Could you please help me with the same? How can I deal with it?